# SEO impact of using non-Latin characters in URL

Tags: seo, url, links, language, character-set

Is there a negative SEO impact if I use non-Latin characters in my URL?

For example, suppose I want to have a page about sweets. I am targeting the keyword `お菓子` which is in Japanese. Should I go for `お菓子.html` or use `sweets.html` instead?

Are Japanese characters present in Latin?

Comment: When you say *latin*, you mean *ASCII*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Some SEOs are wary of using these non-Latin characters in URLs because
>   of the way it might display in certain browsers, or in certain text
>   cases when the link is copied and pasted somewhere online. While
>   having spammy-looking links is never a good thing, I personally think
>   the possible benefit in search results is worth the drawback.
>
> For example, the Japanese Wikipedia page for soccer (サッカー) might
>   display as
>
> `<http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%83%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC>`
>   or as `<http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/サッカー>`, depending on the browser
>   you use.
>
> While some SEOs will be afraid of the potential for your URLs to look
>   spammy with strings of numbers letters and percent signs, the benefit
>   of having the non-Latin characters show up bolded in the URL of your
>   search snippet is worth that, especially when most browsers are
>   displaying the original characters anyway.

**[Source.](https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/are-foreign-language-characters-in-urls-bad-for-seo/536/)**

Comment: Can you bring relevant information from your *Here's a **link*** link into the answer body as a citation block? It will be subject to link rot in the future, and then the info will be lost.

Comment: @Mindwin Every word of the post was quoted verbatim from the linked site.

Answer (score 0):

No, you may get more benefit by using your own language in the URL.
Most search engines are smart enough to distinguish it from encoded non-Latin characters, and it does not look spammy.