# SEO impact of using special letters in a URL

Tags: seo, url

I am in Germany and we have many special letters like *äßö*. Wikipedia uses the letters as is in the URL, but I have heard that only US-ASCII characters should be used.

Are there any actual facts on this, or answers direct from Google? Or it really doesn't matter, just being a matter of visual preference [as stated here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92170/20628)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it affects the SEO but I think it's matter of User Experience. Here's what Google Says about this: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html